# Do I have to specify every router path or can I automate it in vue?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

I have a subclass page where every subclass goes to the same page but depending on the URL It renders differently.

If you click sub1 url will be "../class/sub1" and or if you click sub2 it will be "../class/sub2"

Currently, this is how my router is setup:

```
   const routes = [
  {
    path: "../class/sub1",
    name: "sub1",
    component: SubViewVue,
  },
  {
    path: "../class/sub2",
    name: "sub2",
    component: SubViewVue,
  },
  ]
```

This works but there are 5 classes and each of them has around 8-10 subclass.
Do I have to write this for every subclass or Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [params](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/route-matching-syntax.html#Routes-Matching-Syntax) in Vue Router are for

```
{
  path: "/class/sub:num(\\d+)",
  name: "sub1",
  component: SubViewVue,
},
```

You don't have to include the regex, but if `/sub` is *always* followed by a number you can enforce that in your route matching.  The above will match all paths of the form `/class/sub{number}` where `{number}` is any number of digits.

If you wanted to get the current number of the route in your component code you can do that. Say the current path is `/class/sub5`:

```js
/* Composition API */
<script setup>
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

const route = useRoute()
console.log(route.params) // {num: '5'}
</script>
```